# Line Break for a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to create a program that can group my students randomly into groups of 2. I am working with Ruby on Rails.

I have defined an array on a controller...

```
def index 

@register_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

end
```

and I have placed this code in the view,

```
<%= @register_number.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a %>
```

on the browser, it appears like this.

```
[[10, 4], [3, 1], [9, 6], [7, 5], [2, 8]]
```

But I want them to appear with a line break for each "sub-array" so that it looks neater.

```
[
[10, 4], 
[3, 1], 
[9, 6], 
[7, 5], 
[2, 8] 
]
```

How do I do it on Ruby on Rails? I do not wish to work with ActiveRecord for now. I am just trying to understand Ruby. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, instead of outputing a `to_a` version of your array you should iterate through the each_slice items and print the results.

```
<p>[</p>
<% @register_number.shuffle.each_slice(2) do |duet| %>
<p> [<%= duet.join(', ') %>] </p>
<% end %>
<p>]</p>
```

Comment: Oh my god it works! :) Thank you so much and God bless. I can't vote up because I am (very) new. But thank you again. :)